# GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found) in angular2 with angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm working with angular2 project with angular-cli.
Today I updated version of below to 2.4.1.

```
"@angular/common": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.1",
"@angular/core": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/forms": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/http": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
"angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.24"
```

When I used 2.0.0, it doesn't make an error, but now, it makes an error like `GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found)`.

Even though it makes an error, it's working well.
However, I want to know why it happens, and fix this error.
If anyone knows about this, please let me know.
Thank you :)

**Packages.json**

```js
{
  ...
  
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.33",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bourbon": "^4.2.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.10",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "primeng": "^1.1.0",
    "pubnub-angular2": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "quill": "^1.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "typings": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.33",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "4.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

**angular-cli.json**

```js
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "name": "five-delivery-admin"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": ["assets"],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js",
        "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: From your post it follows that you are typing `http://localhost:4200/null` in your browser. Is it true?

Comment: @K.Daniek, No, I type nothing at all. I just built using ng build.

Comment: Go to your `index.html` file and make sure you have in the `head` tag `<base href="./">`.

Comment: @K.Daniek base href=/

Comment: @K.Daniek it wasn't the problem before. Can it be aproblem??

Comment: Just change your base into this `<base href="./">` or if it still doesn't work, just delete it and try again with no base set at all.

Comment: @K.Daniek, I think it's not a solution for me. It made lots of errors. Thanks though

Answer (score 122, accepted):

So I just had an exhausting time figuring this out, but I did.

This happened to me right after doing an update as well but it had nothing to do with that.

It's definitely from a reference to a variable with a **null** value and it's most likely an image src attribute. At least it was for me and I'm using values from a server all over the place in my app and `img` src were the only things causing this and it makes sense.

I had something similar to this:

`<img [src]="myData?.imageUrl">`

I thought that the `?` safe operator would make sure I didn't get null errors, which it generally does but it seems like when you bind to a `src` attribute, the browser throws an error, not the compiler. The compiler lets you bind null to it because of the safe operator, but because `src` is a reference URL, the browser is still looking for that URL and the console throws the error because it can't find the URL `relative/app/path/null`

The two ways I found to solve this:

1. Use ngIf: `<img *ngIf="myData" [src]="myData.imageUrl"/>` (entire image and its src attribute never even get loaded if theres no data, avoiding the issue entirely)
2. Use interpolation: `<img src="{{ myData?.imageUrl }}"/>` (NOTICE in this solution you still need the safe operator because the compiler will throw an error otherwise, as expected, but now if the value is null, then `src=""` instead of null, which is valid HTML and wont throw a reference error)

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would be intended behavior. @HauntedSmores, are you using AngularFire2 by any chance?

Comment: Nope, not using AngularFire2

Comment: Dude! this was driving me crazy today.  I could not find what was causing this error for the life of me. You nailed it.  I had a safe operator on an src binding, and sure enough that was the root cause.  Thanks a million.

Comment: Perfect! But I still don't know which is the best option to fix. Normally I use '?' notation.

Answer (score 14):

What's happening is that some browsers (i.e. Chrome) perform some `toString` function on the `src` attribute, which causes `null` to become `'null'` instead of `''`, thus triggering to the browser to look for `//domain.com/null`.

Some may remember `ng-src` from AngularJS, which was created to handle this.

---

Anyway, after trying a lot of options, I found the solutions to be:

```
<img [attr.src]="myImageUrl"/>
```

It works for `async` too (which was mainly causing this problem for me):

```
<img [attr.src]="myImageUrl | async"/>
```

---

This works because instead of setting `src` to either `'null'` or `''`, the src attribute *isn't set at all* as long as the variable/path used is not set/resolved, therefor not triggering the error.

Answer (score 8):

An addition to HauntedSmores answer: you can also use a `''`-fallback:

```
[src]="myObj.img || ''"
```

since the elvis-operator `?` is not available in .ts-files, but only in templates, you can also put this into typescript-getters.

Answer (score 1):

**OR**
When their is null/no image in our object then we can give the static image instead

**HTML**

`<img src={{row.webimage?row.webimage:localpath}} />`

**Typescrpit**

```
localpath = '../assets/img/default-user.png'
```

Similarly we can use binding for src attribute.

Answer (score 1):

With a [ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842909/ternary-operator-for-values-in-angular-2-template) operator:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': myVariable ? 'url(' + myVariable.image + ')' : 'none'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was occurring because of using an inexistent property from my template (dumb me). My code was like this:

```
<img [src]='imageUrl'/>
```

But the underlying class for the template was having a property named:

```
imageURL: string;
```

So I changed `imageUrl` for `imageURL` and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the image source path dependent on several async conditions. Until these conditions were resolved the image would not load. So the browser handled it as null and presented this error. The treatment was a simple condition in the template such as:

```
        <span *ngIf="imagePath">
            <img [src]="imagePath" />
        </span>
        <span *ngIf=" ! imagePath">
            Loading image ...
        </span>
```