# Ternary operator for values in Angular 2+ template

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have in my template something like this:

```html
<span *ngIf="selectedSport.key === 'walking'"> steps </span>
<span *ngIf="selectedSport.key !== 'walking'"> km </span>
```

I found this spelling quite ugly, and two lines for this... Meh. So I tried to look for alternatives to this.

**NgIfElse**

```html
<span *ngIf="selectedSport.key === 'walking'; else elseSpan"> steps </span>
<ng-template #elseSpan> km </ng-template>
```

I found this one better, however it may be tricky to use in case of multi-condition like `*ngIf="A && B"`. And we still have two code lines in template...

**get function**

```html
<span> {{getUnit(selectedSport.key)}} </span>
```

```js
getUnit(sportKey: string): string {
   return sportKey === 'walking' ? 'steps' : 'km';
}
```

This is quite better as template gets more readable. However I would like not to add a function in my component for this.

Do you know if Angular 2+ templates support ternary operators as in the `getUnit` function? 
Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Did you try `<span> {{selectedSport.key === 'walking' ? 'steps' : 'km')}} </span>`?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), inside of template like below example

```html
 <span> {{selectedSport.key === 'walking' ? 'steps' : 'km'}} </span>
```

Comment: Thanks, @narendra-jadhav for improving my answer.

Comment: Just to expand on this with regards to an observable value, you must wrap the observable and async pipe in parentheses like {{ (someObs$ | async) === 'someValue' ? 'output if true' : 'output if false' }}

Answer (score 2):

- It seems that you are trying to display unit of selected sport.
- It is better to keep the logic in controller and populate it in model
  object and view just display the model.
- Diluting the logic in
  view layer may not a better design and violates law of single
  responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

if you want multiple ternary operator you can use like that

```
 <span >{{this.commentsType === itemType.All ? counter.allCounts : this.commentsType === itemType.Project ? counter.projectCount : this.commentsType === itemType.Customer ? counter.customerCommunication : 0}}</span>
```