# how to pass html tag in Ternary Conditional Operator

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Ternary Conditional Operator in my angular project, but when I am trying to pass HTML tag inside condition I am getting an error, how to resolve it,
Code -

```
{{!status.available ? 'Inactive' : 'Active'}}
```

this code is working fine but when I try to pass -

```
{{!status.available ? '<span>Inactive</span>' : 'Active'}}
```

Getting this error on client side - {{!status.available ? '' : 'Active'}}
I want to display -  Inactive/active only

Comment: This response will help you [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842909/ternary-operator-for-values-in-angular-2-template) .

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do like this :

```js
<span>
{{!status.available ? 'Inactive' : 'Active'}}
</span>
```

Comment: hi, @othmane I want to pass link - {{!status.available ?<span>Inactive</span>' : <span>Active</span>}}
I have to pass data (active/inactive)  inside HTML tage